# OutOfMemory using setImageUri

Tags: android, memory, android-fragments, uri, out-of-memory

I have a ViewPagerActivity with a lot of fragment ( swipe view ) . Each fragment contains an imageView. Sometimes, when I navigate between these fragments, I have an error :

```
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:650)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at    android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromStream(Drawable.java:741)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:631)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.widget.ImageView.setImageURI(ImageView.java:379)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at com.thesnowcoach.android.jpgviewer.JpgFragment.loadNewCourse(JpgFragment.java:381)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at com.thesnowcoach.android.jpgviewer.JpgFragment.onCreateView(JpgFragment.java:199)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
11-25 23:22:05.880: E/AndroidRuntime(15019):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
```

The code :

```
private void loadNewCourse(int times) {

        Display display = this.getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

        int height = display.getHeight();

        mImageSwitcher.getLayoutParams().height=height;

        barLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(cours.getCategorie()
                .getCouleur().getR(), cours.getCategorie().getCouleur().getV(),
                cours.getCategorie().getCouleur().getB()));
        // Ajout du titre de la progression Ã  la fenetre
        titreCours = (TextView) barLayout.findViewById(R.id.titreCours);
        titreCours.setText(cours.getTitre());
        mImages = JpgViewerTools.loadPicturesFromSDCardExcept(absolutePath + File.separator
                + cours.getId());

        slidesSize = mImages.size();

        mDifferentSlidesSize = ViewPagerActivity.slidesSize;
        displaySlidesCount();
        if (times == 0) {
            barState = BarState.ELLAPSED;
        } else
            barState = BarState.ELLAPSED;
        mImageSwitcher.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(mImages
                .get(getArguments().getInt("position")))));

        state = setState(getArguments().getInt("position"));
    }
```

How can I solve this problem ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When using a pager, all the images are kept in memory. One problem can occur if you switch pages to quickly. To solve this add a small delay between reading swipes. Secondly, if the files are to big then you will receive this error over time as the stack builds up. Consider reducing the image size or dropping pages after a certain number and adding them if you need them later. Lastly, if you are using an emulator to test your device, you may simply need to increase the memory of the emulator.

Comment: How can I drop pages after a certain number and add them if I need them later ?
If i use a thread to load each images, can it solve the problem ?

Comment: Keep an array or list of items in each page and a position. When you move position then update the pages that you show

Comment: Have you an example ? Because I have some difficulties to understand how to implements that